# Matlab: How to smooth colors of matrix in plot3( ) function?

Tags: matlab, colors, plot, smoothing

I am using plot3 to plot a matrix such that the resultant figure shows different colors for each vector of that matrix:

```
plot3(Grid.x1(:,:),Grid.x2(:,:),phi(:,:))
```

[image]

How can I smooth the coloring of this plot? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [varycolor](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21050) from FileExchange to construct and control a continuous range color spectrum. This way the transition between different lines will seem more natural and proximal lines will have similar colors.

You can read more and see examples usage here http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/08/15/colors-for-your-multi-line-plots/

**Example**:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(128);

% raw plot3()
figure; plot3(X, Y, Z);
```

[image]

```
% define set equal to line number
ColorSet = varycolor(128);

% smooth plot3()
figure; hold all;
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', ColorSet);
plot3(X, Y, Z); view(3);
```

[image]

**Update**:
For a continuous 3D plot (i.e. a surface) you can use `surfl` instead of `plot3` and display your data as a 3-D [Surface Plot (with Shading)](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/graf2d2.html#3). You can additionally apply any `colormap` on the resulting surface, i.e. `gray` or `ColorSet` as above.

```
surfl(X,Y,Z);
shading interp;
colormap(gray);
```

[image]

Comment: gevang: Thanks for the answer, but I want the plot to look smooth which means that I would like to get rid of the white spaces between the lines representing vectors of the matrix.

Comment: @S_H "smooth" wasn't clear from the original post, especially since you asked for "smooth the coloring of the plot". What you need is a surface plot instead of individual 3D plots. See my updated answer on a suggestion.